# Replace individual colors in multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting

### The goal

Replace individual colors in a multi-layer Photoshop document in a way that is flexible and efficient enough to be done a multiple times in the production process—like when I need to update the colors or edit layer content. I have a palette of 5-10 colors used in many different layers (all layers are multi-color raster images), and I want to be able to arbitrarily replace them, without having to do a lot of manual work each time.

Is it possible to do this with adjustment layers (or anything else)?

### How I tried and failed to do this with Adjustment Layers

> **Idea #1:** For each color you want to replace, add a `Replace color` adjustment layer, configured to replace the old color with the new color.

**Problem:** There is no `Replace color` adjustment layer (as of CS6).

> **Idea #2:** For each color you want to replace, add a color-changing Adjustment Layer (such as `Hue/Saturation`) with a `Color range` mask selecting the old color (let's assume it's yellow).

**Problem:** As soon as you add/move/recolor anything yellow in the layers below, the mask will no longer be accurate. The mask does not *dynamically* select yellow—it just stays the same as it was when you set it up. (I don't know if it's even possible to make a dynamically updating mask that's tied to the content of lower layers, but I would love to hear how if it is.) So, if you want the mask to be updated, you have to manually update it. This tediousness is what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to do this sort of color replacement, using adjustment layers, masks, or any other technique, like actions or scripts?

Comment: Well you could use illustrator and something that photoshop doesn't have: Global swatches. :) -- Similar question:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop

Comment: There IS replace color in CS6.

Comment: @Scott `Replace color` exists on its own, but not as an Adjustment Layer.

Comment: So you need to do this to several layers but retain the overal layer structure of the file? You could easily use Replace Color on several Layers. Holding down the Option/Alt key when you select the menu item causes the adjustment to load with the last used settings.

Comment: You can also make several replacements with a single `Hue/Saturation` adjustment layer

Comment: @Joonas In theory Illustrator would be great for this, but in practice Illustrator makes the workflow extremely awkward for coloring and editing my hand-drawn line art. I find that some things that take a second in Photoshop (things that I'd do in PS with the a combination of the pencil tool/paint bucket/wand) can be painful in AI, and the tools that are supposed to facilitate this kind of editing (like LivePaint and the blob brush) make it impossible to maintain order and separation in the layers.

Comment: @Const A `Hue/Saturation` adjustment layer would affect the colors equally (by the same % H/S/L, etc), but I need to make arbitrary replacements of individual colors.

Comment: @Scott If I am replacing 4 colors and there are 20 layers, I'd have to repeat that 80 times. So I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: I'm going to have to say.. stick to CS5 then. Your workflow seems to require it. I disagree about Illustrator, layer organizing in object-based applications isn't as imperative as it often is in raster based applications. And if you're dealing with flat color and keylines, AI will absolutely be faster for editing (provided you're proficient with it).

Comment: @Scott Not sure what you mean about sticking to CS5.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were saying 5 did allow replace color as an adjustment layer. I see it doesn't. Have you tried a selective color adjustment layer?

Comment: @Scott Same as with the other adjustment layers, you can't use it to alter specific colors without depending on masks.

Comment: Have you ever thought of making individual files out of your layers and changing them then recombining them? Just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to achieve this:

1. Use <kbd>Select > Color Range</kbd> (after this you can `Save selection` to keep this mask if you want)
2. Create a new layer on top of all other layers with the color you want to replace, name the new layer something like 'color overlay - blue'
3. Use `Paint Bucket` to fill the color selection in the new layer

Now you have a color overlay layer for the color you wanted to replace, Also, when you select this layer and then <kbd>Select > All</kbd>, you will have the same mask you had when you used Color Range at the beginning of the process (i.e. you can use this layer to quickly overlay any color you want)

Comment: To expand on your answer, I found [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JIZymCmvqU) helpful. The author shows how to use a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer to match another color exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[This script](http://konradkolasa.roon.io/color-each-photoshop-script) will allow you to select various layers and change them all to one same colour at the same time, without dealing with masks or selections.
It will work on any solid-colour layer with a mask or shape layers.

Comment: This seems to be what I need, but the script doesn't seem to exist. Can you maybe post the script in the post itself or perhaps update the link?

Comment: Internet Archive copy of the original website is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140304230147/http://konradkolasa.roon.io/color-each-photoshop-script), but the original script [download link](http://d.pr/f/qANj) was not archived.

Comment: I tracked down Konrad Kolasa, and got him to send me the JSX. I have uploaded it to the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/color-each-jsx) for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

**Selective Color** is one thing you can try.

Another idea is to use a "**Gradient Map**". Both can be found under the adjustment layer.