# Change PSD's color with variables?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, palette

I have a PSD of a website design. I like the layout but I would like to experiment with the color palette. Is there a way to swap colors? I was think something like variablizing the colors and then quickly swapping them or importing a color palette from Kuler.

This is what I'm looking at:

[image: Color Scheme]

Comment: Are you using smart objects, shape layers or regular layers?

Comment: @AndrewH regular layers.

Comment: See similar thread [Replace individual colors in multiple layers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/replace-individual-colors-in-multiple-layers). I am not sure how you could easily change a whole color scheme with a variable. It would be much easier if you only had to do this in CSS.

Comment: Another similar thread [Change the color of multiple layers at once in CS4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21591/change-the-color-of-multiple-layers-at-once-in-cs4?rq=1)

Comment: @AndrewH, You're right it is easier in CSS and I think I'm spoiled because I work with CSS more. I just wanted to experiment with colors and this layout without have to touch each layer.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the layout and a screenshot of your layers by any chance? At least something to give me an idea of what you're looking at.

Comment: @Ryan https://www.evernote.com/l/ABSZDS7Bv6tCcY6yNloJE7ff2auPG4T8hCoB/image.png

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/ABSZDS7Bv6tCcY6yNloJE7ff2auPG4T8hCoB/image.png

Comment: While the duplicate link points to one specific similar question... there are a ton of questions that are essentially the same as this here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=Photoshop+color+theme -- As it stands Photoshop as no way to dynamically reassign colors... there are multiple questions here though all with various workarounds for it... which one works for you is kind of up to you.

Comment: You could get your colors from smart objects, as shown here: https://youtu.be/qkgsGhwG7rI?t=258

Comment: That is if you're using Adobe CC 2015 of course.