# How to change colour across multiple layers in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting

I've seen this type of question asked before, but I've not seen a satisfactory answer:

I have a specific colour palette, and I can not stray from it at all; I have a specific green (32,144,24) on 93 layers, and I want to change it to a specific blue (24,32,144) on every layer.
I have 3 different colours on each layer, and multiple palettes to go through and export (93 layers * 3 colour replacements * X number of palettes = no way I'm doing it manually.)

Because of that, I decided to look for a script to do it for me.
I found two such scripts, but they both return errors when running, and do absolutely nothing.

I have no experience with javascript, so I wouldn't even know where to begin with writing my own script.

Met with no luck on my own, I decided to ask the internet for help.

Thanks in advance for actually reading the OP and offering any relevant advice.
-John Shmoe

Edit:
Two such topics I've viewed that yielded no results:
[Replace individual colors in multiple layers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/replace-individual-colors-in-multiple-layers)
[Change the color of multiple layers at once in CS4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21591/change-the-color-of-multiple-layers-at-once-in-cs4)

Example:
[image]
Replace colour 1 with colour A, colour 2 with colour B, etc. on every layer 
(again, imagine there are so many that doing it one-by-one would be ridiculous to even suggest.)

Comment: Could you tell us which questions you've looked at that didn't work? Otherwise I anticipate this will get closed as a duplicate. See this one for example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13787/408 Also what kind of layers are they? This may be relevant: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30660/408 Though honestly because you have multiple colors per layer I anticipate this will be rather difficult.  Have you tried replace color?

Comment: @Johannes Using replace color would take even longer than using the fill tool.
Unless, of course, there's a way to have it influence **all** of my layers at once instead of one-at-a-time, like I stated I need in my OP.
However, I have not seen such an option for the replace color tool.

Comment: Where you begin with writing your own script or editing an existing script to do what you need is the Photoshop Scripting Guide that matches your version of Photoshop. It is worth considering to learn how to script Photoshop if you are going to make documents with this level of complexity, because the time you spend learning to script it will be less than the time you spend manually doing laborious grunt work. It is not as complicated as you might think because you already know Photoshop. If you are on a Mac, you can script with AppleScript that is written like plain English.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments use `Replace Color`. True, you'll need to run it for each layer (although you could do it for every layer automatically, keep reading) but it will be much faster than using the fill tool.

Why is that? Well because you can turn replace color into an action. This will require some initial set-up:

1. Go to your layer and replace color. Before hitting apply, make sure
   you save it.
2. Repeat step one for each color you want to replace on
   the layer.
3. Create an action.
4. While the action is recording, go to
   `Replace Color` and `load` your saved files and apply them.
5. Repeat step 4 for each
   one you saved in step 1.
6. Stop the action.

Now you can do this action (and assign it to a keyboard shortcut for speed) and repeat it for every layer.

You can do this for all layers as well but the process will be a bit more drawn out and really is only worth it if you have a *lot* of layers.

Do as I said above, and create the action. Then go to `File -> Scripts -> Export Layers To Files...` and go through that process. Now with each layer being saved out as its own image go to `File -> Automate -> Batch` and select your directory of images and the action you created. Run that.

If you're happy with that, you're done! Otherwise, if you want all your images back in one PSD go to Bridge and select your directory of images and go to `Tools -> Photoshop -> Load Files into Photoshop Layers...`

Now you should have what you started with more or less but with adjusted colors.

Any other solution would probably have to rely on external scripting, but that is also a worthwhile skill to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would help you.

Add Color overlay to one of your layer. 
Then copy the layer style.
Select all layer(93 of them).
Paste the copied layer style to all of them.

This should work out.

Comment: did you post another answer as user58220 before?

Comment: yes, my account was as GUEST as this was my first time on graphic designs. Later logged in as my name was not show.

Comment: Alright thanks for clarifying. Also I'd note that your answer will only work if there's 1 colors per layer. OP mentions they have 3 colors per layer. Color overlay would change all the colors on the layer.