# Is there a Photoshop (CS5) plugin that will make color swatches global?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I am trying to find a way to make global color changes in a single place.  I found another question that describes this well... [Is it possible to have global color swatches or color styles in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop?newreg=c22175e483c14ad6a0438c9242c61525).  Per the answers to that post/question, Photoshop CS5 does not support "global swatches".  So, my new question is...

Are there any plugins for Photoshop CS5 that enable "global swatch" type functionality or in some other way achieve the objective outlined in the question linked above?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of the question you've linked to. I doubt asking again will get different answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. Photoshop is raster based so we deal with pixels or more accurately said, we deal with color channels. Layers are really masks that affect color channels.
However you can make your dream come true by designing whatever you design in a clever way. For example text can be turned into shapes and then use them as masks of a solid color layer that you can change. So ... in general you want to have 1 mask, masking a solid color. If you are lazy, you can flatten the design Ctrl+Alt+Shift+E, and then use Replace Color in the Image->Adjustment. If you really have a very specific color, you will change it easily.
Good luck.

Comment: Ivan is right, unfortunately Adobe hasn't found a way yet to build that in, lets hope some day we wil be able to have it :)