# How to make a design's color palette easy to change in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a good practice to follow when creating a design in Photoshop so that it's easy to change colors later on?

For example, if it's possible to create a color swatch where I reference a color slot in my swatch instead of the color code. So PS would know that in that layer I'm using the color slot #3 from my swatch. When I later change the color in slot #3 then all places referencing that color would update.

Comment: Hi there! This question has been asked before, take a look:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop

Comment: There is this extension: http://www.codeadventure.com/prisma I'm just waiting for the CC 2014 version...