# How do I update a custom gradient preset that I've made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I have a PSD that uses the same gradient about 20 times.

Can I update that one gradient so that all 20 instance are updated as well?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop offers no ability to apply colors in a "global" manner.

There are some clever workarounds using smart objects or thrid-party tools:  [Is it possible to have global color swatches or color styles in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop)

But, essentially, **no** you can't directly.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is, you can save a custom gradient.   Then use the automated functions in photoshop [ Window - Actions ] assign a new action and simply go through the process once, then save it. and record them on the event log.   then just re-apply the event log 20 times in each individual circumstance.

Hope this helps

Comment: Keep in mind,   the method I suggested is not an automated script to apply the same gradient to all,   just simply a faster way of doing it consistently over again. If it is what it sounds like it shouldn't take more than a few mins

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a Photoshop action in which you use a gradient. If the gradient is copied as a layer and placed to a different location, you are out of luck. But if it is a saved gradient, yes, you can open any Photoshop file, load that gradient, make your changes, and save it with the same name your action should now produce the gradient with the new colors or transitions in all 20 instances.

So, the answer to your ambiguous question is a "Definite maybe!"