# Is it possible to change the colors of [all] layers at once in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color

I went too far, but even if I didn't, I might want to change the color scheme in a future project.

Is there a simple way to select all layers and change a layer? I did some searching and couldn't find a way. I'm pretty sure there isn't, but if there is, please tell me.

Comment: can you explain you question a bit more by adding some snapshot of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: There are some methods, but none of them are perfect. Photoshop lacks "global swatches", which would be the ideal solution. [There's this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13787/2332). The most solid answer there is probably [the one by Dominik Guzei](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/49357/2332) Note that you can also get that  [Prisma extension from Creative market](https://creativemarket.com/DominikGuzei/242240-Prisma-Global-Color-Swatches). To be fair, there is also another [similar extension called ColorKit](https://creativemarket.com/MakeTheWeb/187310-ColorKit).

Comment: These extensions work similarly, but there are small differences. I prefer Prisma, for few reasons: **1.** Prisma swatches are synced with the Prisma account.  **2.** In Prisma it's easier to tell which layers have been given a color swatch. You still have to select a layer to know for sure that it's been given a swatch, but Colorkit gives no indication, so there's that. **3.** The gui is a bit better in my opinion.

Comment: You could use the layer styles. For example, create the first color change with the style, and then apply that to all others. This assumes you are going to change everything to the same color etc. You could use the SmartSwatch method too, but it's long!

Comment: Someone can go ahead and add the prisma to the answer. Ill choose it, and star it for future notice. This looks like what Im looking for, thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, group the layers and apply a Color Overlay effect to that group on Layer Style panel.

If you can't group, apply the Color Overlay effect to just one layer. Then, on Layer Panel, right click that layer and choose Copy Layer Style. Select all the other layers and right click > Paste Layer Style.

Also, you could create a new layer style and then apply it to all the layers you want.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it helps.