# re-color a whole design to test different pallete in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I created a dashboard design for one of my clients and we would like to test different color options. most of the elements are smart objects. needless to say there are many layers, organized in folders (just as I like it :))

Is there any quick and easy way to change each color without going thru every single layer here? (not talking about "color overlay")

for eaxmple, I want to select all orange elements and change their color to pink. all blue elements to green.. and so on. This way I will be able to export different color versions easily but most importantly - quickly!

thanks for your help!

here is a screenshot[image]

Comment: You should consider using illustrator for these kinds of designs. Not only is it more natural but changing this color would have been a breeze. But yes some plugins for global color apparently exist

Comment: @joojaa that's your personal opinion, not a fact. For example I would never recommend Illustrator for interfaces like this, as it's simply not meant for this and not natural to me at all. I would recommend Sketch, you would also be able to change colorschemes quite easily.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Sure sketch is also a good option, but odds are OP has an Illustrator license. OTOH we do not know if he has sketch, or even a machine capable of running it. But in this case illustrator is more natural than Photoshop as all elements are describable by vectors. In this case the usability boost is a fact.

Comment: Maybe this [question is a duplicate](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop)? If so the answers there should help.

Comment: Thanks guys, still no resolution here.. as to PS vs. Ai - it's always a question, personally for me it's easier to use PS. @joojaa - do you know of any specific plugin for this purpose?

Comment: choice of slftware should not be about what you find easier. Otherwise you can never explore new things and your stuck with one way.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Move Tool (hotkey: V) with auto-select turned on and change colors of single elements, but it still gonna take some time. However, it is significantly faster than changing colors in all your smart objects individually. Cheers, hope that helped!

EDIT: Make yourself an automated action for a single-click color-change, repeat that for every color you wish to change and viola. Here's a link to a tutorial on using actions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuVnLOxEhnI  it's made by Phlearn, a generally good resource on using Adobe products.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was doing up until now, but it just takes so long, very time consuming.. I am looking for an easier, faster, automated-like solution.

Comment: @Waterlily I'll reply in the answer with edit ; )